# I keep on getting index error. i dont know where should i change my code. here are my codes

Tags: python

```
def disp_sss():
    print ("\n\nList of SSS loans\n")
    print ("EmployeeNo        SSS        Deduction")
    for idx in range(len(EmpNo)):
        print (" {0:15} {1:10s} {2:10.2f}".format(EmpNo[idx], SSSLoan[idx], float(MonthlyDeduction[idx])))
```

im trying to display the data from a text file. this is the erro message. 
line 87, in disp_sss
    print (" {0:15} {1:10s} {2:10.2f}".format(EmpNo[idx], SSSLoan[idx], float(MonthlyDeduction[idx])))
IndexError: list index out of range

the thing is, when i run the program, it displays all the data but after dsiplaying the data, the error start to appear. here is the display im getting  respectively.
EmployeeNo        SSS        Deduction
 123              500           200.00
 a1001            300            20.00

Comment: The error trace should tell you what line it's on. I suspect in the "for idx in range len(EmpNo)". Why is the length of the employee number relevant?

Comment: You have probably different length of EmpNo or SSSLoan or MonthlyDeduction.

Comment: What is `EmpNo`? You never define it in the code.

Comment: in disp_sss print (" {0:15} {1:10s} {2:10.2f}".format(EmpNo[idx], SSSLoan[idx], float(MonthlyDeduction[idx])))
IndexError: list index out of range... this the error

Comment: Check out [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: One of your lists is probably shorter than EmpNo. But as you didn't provide us neither with a [mcve] nor with a complete error traceback, there's just no way we can tell what is going on.

Comment: Either `SSSLoan` or `MonthlyDeduction` is of size less than `EmpNo`. That's all we can say with provided info.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your SSLoan/MonthlyDeduction do not have the same length as EmpNo.

TO debug, first try just removing those two at once, then add it one by one to see where the real problem is.

Alternatively, you might consider storing them into a dataframe and display the dataframe, which might have better look.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating an index over the list `EmpNo`, but you're trying to use the same index on two other lists, `SSSLoan` and `MonthlyDeduction`, so if any of the two lists has fewer items, it would cause an `IndexError` when the iteration gets to a point where the index exists for `EmpNo` but not for `SSSLoan` or `MonthlyDeduction`.

You should make sure that the 3 lists are of equal length. Alternatively, you can use `zip` the 3 lists so that the iteration would end when the shortest list is exhausted:

```
def disp_sss():
    print("\n\nList of SSS loans\n")
    print("EmployeeNo        SSS        Deduction")
    for row in zip(EmpNo, SSSLoan, MonthlyDeduction):
        print(" {0:15} {1:10s} {2:10.2f}".format(row))
```